# Spring-security ldap fallback

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, ldap

I have configured authentication so that I have both inMemoryAuthentication and ldapAuthentication coexisting. My problem is that, when the LDAP server is not accessible, I get a ConnectException (so far so good) and it seems like it doesn't check the inMemoryAuthentication configuration at all.
I try to find a way to be able to configure a fallback when the LDAP server is not reachable.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
        LOG.debug("Adding default app user");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("pass").roles("USER");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Error adding default app user", ex);
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
    }

    ...

    try {
        auth.ldapAuthentication()
        .userDnPatterns(ldapDn).groupSearchBase(ldapGroup)
        .contextSource().url(ldapUrl);
        LOG.debug("Configured");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        LOG.error("Error during configuration of LDAP auth.", ex);
    }
}
```

This is done in a subclass of WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.

As I said, everything works fine when the LDAP server is reachable but the inMemoryAuthentication doesn't work when the LDAP server is gone.

Any ideas welcomed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi grekler, have you solved this?

Comment: Hi RLuceac. What I actually did is adding a check for availability of the ldap server before configuring it in spring security. I mean I enclosed the second try-catch in an if(ldapAvailable()) and in this method trying to connect. Dirty but doing what I needed.

Comment: Implementing the ldapAvailable() method was easy ?

Comment: @Stephane It has been quite some time since I did this so I don't recall exactly how it was done however I recall it was quite simple. Basically, you can start by checking if a connection exists (and is alive) and, eventually, a simple query to confirm you get LDAP responses